# how to change gender column's values to numeric values in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data frame with gender column and unfortunately gender column was filled with free text such as: `male, female, m, f, Male, Female, Demiguy, none, Trans, Cisgender, non-binary, She/her/they/them, Other, Cis, SWM, NB, Genderfluid, Nonbinary/femme` etc..

I want to correct these values as `male=0`, `female=1` and `other=2`.

I tried a few `data.table` methods but I can't figure it out.

Comment: hi, can you add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no codes.. I've tried %like% operator in order to catch the pattern because these values are repeating and there are hundreds of values. But I could not write any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe u can try and tweak:

```
DT[, GENDER := 2]
DT[toupper(X) %chin% c("M","MAN","BOY") | grepl("male", X, ignore.case=TRUE), GENDER := 0]
DT[toupper(X) %chin% c("F","WOMAN","GIRL") | grepl("female", X, ignore.case=TRUE), GENDER :=1]
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(X=c("Malel","male","female","m","f","Male","Female","Demiguy",
    "none","Trans","Cisgender","non-binary","She/her/they/them","Other","Cis",
    "SWM","NB","Genderfluid","Nonbinary/femme"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to do something like this. Free text is a pain.

```
library(dplyr)
male_terms <- c("Male","male","man","Man","m")
female_terms <- c("Female","female","woman","Woman","f")
x <- x %>%
    mutate(gender_bin = if_else(gender %in% male_terms,0,
                          if_else(gender %in% female_terms,1,2)))
```

Comment: alternatively using data.table, `DT[, GENDER := 2][X %chin% male_terms, GENDER := 0][X %chin% female_terms, GENDER := 1]`

Comment: Than you for your answer. It works but there are also some misspelling values (I forgot to mention) like "Malel".. In this code, malel=2 but in fact it has to be 0?? @chinsoon12